# Behavior of VHDL comparison operator with integer argument

Tags: vhdl

Consider the following example, compiling with VHDL-2008 support.

```
library ieee;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;
...
if (to_unsigned(0, 3) <= 8) then
   StatementsA
end if;
if (to_unsigned(1, 3) <= 8) then
   StatementsB
end if;
```

In my experience, `StatementsA` get executed, but not `StatementsB`.
Logically I would expect that both statements get executed since 0 and 1 are both less than 8. My theory is that 8 is interpreted as a 3 bit number, and the top bit is being lost, creating the value of 0.

**Questions**

1. Is this the intended behavior of VHDL?
2. What is the logic/reasoning behind this? Why wouldn't the size of the comparison automatically be resized to the required size of the integer?
3. What is a logical & safe practice to encourage in order to avoid situations like this?

Comment: Hi Josh. Neither Simon nor I can reproduce what you are seeing. Can you please double check?

Comment: @Philippe Yes, I am revisiting now. I too am having problems reproducing and wonder if there is something going on that I did not correctly describe.

Comment: if this question was in error, please close it. It will confuse future readers.

Comment: @Philippe yes, I have found my error. The problem was not in this operator, but when using the ? operator (as in ?> ?=, etc). This question should be closed. I have voted as such.

Answer (score 2):

I cannot confirm the behavior that you are seeing "*in your experience*". Here is my [vetsmod](http://sigasi.com/vetsmod) code example.

```
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;
entity e is
end entity e;

architecture RTL of e is
begin
        name : process is
        begin
                if (to_unsigned(0, 3) <= 8) then
                        report "StatementsA";
                end if;
                if (to_unsigned(1, 3) <= 8) then
                        report "StatementsB";
                end if;
                wait;
        end process name;
end architecture RTL;
```

Compile and run with ModelSim:

```
# run 5us 
# ** Note: StatementsA
#    Time: 0 ps  Iteration: 0  Instance: /e
# ** Note: StatementsB
#    Time: 0 ps  Iteration: 0  Instance: /e
#  exit
```

Can you double-check and update your question?

Answer (score 0):

Incidentally, what compiler are you using? I wrote a small dummy program containing the statements above and statementB does get executed! I'm using Modelsim.

Comment: No, the compiler does not convert the integer to unsigned. There is a function `"<="(unsigned, natural)` that handles this.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you didnt actually mean

```
library ieee;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;
...
if (to_unsigned(0, 3) <= 8) then
    StatementsA
elsif (to_unsigned(1, 3) <= 8) then
    StatementsB
end if;
```

This statement would produce the behavior you are suggesting. VHDL doesn't technically "short circuit" if-elsif-else statements. They will all execute synchronously or asynchronously; however the compiler WILL build in priority.

I guess the developers realized that most programmers write if-elsif-else structures intending the statements to execute in a certain order. To accommodate this programming perception, there are enable latches for each output of the if-elsif-else structure. The first conditional statement that returns a TRUE enables the output for the current condition. In this way the developers maintain the "priority" we expect while retaining the reality of hardware descriptive languages. Take a look at the block diagrams and you will see what I mean. I believe the enable works by ANDing the NOT of the previous conditional and the current conditional. If the previous condition is true the enable is turned off for all statements below that conditional statement. If its false the enable is possible for all conditionals below that one.